# EasyPHP 5.3.9, no available PHP extensions

Tags: php, configuration, php-extension, easyphp

This is a problem i wasn't able to solve despite extensive searches on the Internet or on the easyPHP website.

I just installed EasyPHP 5.3.9 and was running previously on EasyPHP 5.3.8. Of course, some PHP extensions are missing, but when I try to enable them (EasyPHP > PHP extension > ..), the list of available extensions comes EMPTY !

I still have the 5.3.8 installed and it show the available extensions that i can select...

[image: easyPHP extensions missing]

Is this a bug or has anyone already encountered this?

Comment: Consider asking the EasyPHP support directly for a solution

Comment: I went to support but could not find an answer in the FAQ or forum yet...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found a (pretty sure NON ACEDEMIC solution) after some blind tests !!

Comparing the 5.3.8 and 5.3.9 install files I noticed that i had a folder named "php539x120619095337" in the 3.9 instead of just "php" in the 3.8 (inside are the extensions in the /ext folder by the way).

I just copied the content of this weird folder in the EasyPHP 5.3.9/php folder.

SUMMARY : 
C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-5.3.9\php\php539x120619095337 > CONTENT moved to
C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-5.3.9\php

It worked... weird...

Comment: In newer version of EasyPHP (12.1), this seems to have unwanted side-effects. 
Instead of moving the files, I've resorted to enabling extensions directly in php.ini file - which, in your case, would be `C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-5.3.9\php\php539x120619095337\php.ini`

Answer (score 0):

Usando un VPS la manera mas facil de recompilar PHP

http://www.lkperu.com/2014/01/29/tutoriales-compilar-php-con-easyphp-en-un-vps/

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.